# Python: how to extract data from Odata API that contains pages @odata.nextLink

Tags: python, api, odata

I need to pull data from an Odata API. With code below I do receive data, but only 250 rows.

The JSON contains a key called: `@odata.nextLink` that contains one value, this is the `BASE_URL + endpoint + ?$skip=250`

How can I loop through the next pages?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

BASE_URL = "base_url"


def session_token():
    url = BASE_URL + '/api/oauth/token'

    headers = {"Accept": "application\json",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"}

    body = {"username":"user",
            "password": "pwd",
            "grant_type": "password"}

    return "Bearer "+ requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = body).json()["access_token"]

def make_request(endpoint, token = session_token()):
    headers = {"Authorization": token}
    response = requests.get(BASE_URL + endpoint, headers = headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)
        return json_data


make_request("/odata/endpoint")
```

Following @Marek Piotrowski's advise I modified and came to a solution:

```
def main():
    url = "endpoint"
    while True:
        if not url:
            break
        response = make_request("endpoint")
        if response.status_code == 200:
            json_data = json.loads(response.text)
            url = json_data["@odata.nextLink"] # Fetch next link
            yield json_data['value']

result = pd.concat((json_normalize(row) for row in main()))
print(result) # Final dataframe, works like a charm :)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that would retrieve all records, I believe (assuming there's `@odata.nextLink` in `json_data` indeed):

```
def retrieve_all_records(endpoint, token = session_token()):
    all_records = []
    headers = {"Authorization": token}
    url = BASE_URL + endpoint
    while True:
        if not url:
            break
        response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            json_data = json.loads(response.text)
            all_records = all_records + json_data['records']
            url = json_data['@odata.nextLink']
    return all_records
```

The code is untested, though. Let me know if it works. Alternatively, you could make some recursive call to `make_request`, I believe, but you'd have to store results somewhere above the function itself then.

Comment: And the ```?$skip=250``` part?

Comment: You wrote it yourself that odata.nextLink contains that already, right? I imagine that next `odata.nextLink` is gonna skip first 500 entries and so on.

Comment: Thanks, got my solution. Implement your advise and added some logic :)

Comment: Great to hear that! Would appreciate if you accepted the answer then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is late, but you could look at this article from [Towards Data Science of Ephram Mwai](https://towardsdatascience.com/querying-microsoft-graph-api-with-python-269118e8180c)

He pretty solved the problem with a good script.

Comment: The article you linked is behind a paywall. Can you summarize it?